# 402 Bad Request using Python, Nginx, and flask on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, flask, raspbian

I am trying to get my Python application to run on port 80 so I can host my page to the Internet and see my temperature and all that remotely.

I get a 402 Bad Request error and I can't seem to figure out why. It seems it's having trouble writting my .sock file to a temp directory.

I am following this tutorial.

https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/python-flask-web-application-on-raspberry-pi-with-nginx-and-uwsgi/

/home/pi/sampleApp/sampleApp.py

```
from flask import Flask
first_app = Flask(__name__)

@first_app.route("/")
def first_function():
 return "<html><body><h1 style='color:red'>I am hosted on Raspberry Pi   !!!</h1></body></html>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
 first_app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

/home/pi/sampleApp/uwsgi_config.ini

```
[uwsgi]

chdir = /home/pi/sampleApp
module = sample_app:first_app

master = true
processes = 1
threads = 2

uid = www-data 
gid = www-data
socket = /tmp/sample_app.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

/etc/rc.local just before exit 0

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/pi/sampleApp/uwsgi_config.ini --uid www- data --gid www-data --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/sample_app_proxy and I verified this moved to sites-enabled after I linked it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/sample_app.sock;
    }
}
```

I got all the way to the final step with 100 percent success. After I linked the sample_app_proxy file so it gets copied into /nginx/sites-enabled/ I do a service nginx restart. When I open my browser 'localhost' I get a 502 Bad Request.

I noticed in the nginx logs at the bottom that there was an error.

```
2017/01/29 14:49:08 [crit] 1883#0: *8 connect() to unix:///tmp/sample_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/sample_app.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

My source code is exactly as you see it in the tutorial, I checked it over many times.

I looked at the /etc/logs/uwsgi.log and found this message at the bottom.

```
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7336
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.
```

I am not sure what is going on and why it doesn't seem to write the .sock file to the /tmp/ directory. The test I did earlier in the tutorial worked fine and the sample_app.sock file showed up in /tmp/ But when I run the application it doesn't seem to work.

I did a lot of searching and I saw many posts saying to use "///" instead on "/" in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/sample_app_proxy file, but whether I use one or three, I still get the 502 error.

```
uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/sample_app.sock;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the last step I need to accomplish so I can do remote stuff to my home. Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the socket being created in `/tmp/sample_app.sock`?

Comment: I saw it being created when I did the test earlier in the tutorial.

Comment: This was the test uwsgi --ini /home/pi/sampleApp/uwsgi_config.ini and then it says to grep for the file in /tmp/. When I do this, the file does show up. But after I do sudo service nginx restart at the end of the tutorial, if I grep for the file in /tmp/ it isn't there.